# Get the key of an unknown entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, primary-key, state, dbcontext

Hello I would like to get the primary key value.

```
public static void Look(LEBAEntities db, object obj) {
    // if getPrimaryKey(obj) == 0
    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Added;

    // else
    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Is there a function or any way to get the primary key with Entity Framework?

Comment: Code-first? Or Database-first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is several solutions:

1- Your entities inherit from a `Base Class` which base class has `Id` property and you make `Look` method generic:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    protected BaseEntity()
    {
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public static void Look<TEntity>(LEBAEntities db, TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity {
    if(entity.Id == 0)
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    else
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

2- You can use `GetProperties` method via reflection and compare the property name:

```
public static void Look(LEBAEntities db, object obj) {
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var key = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => 
        p.Name.Equals("ID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
        || p.Name.Equals(type.Name + "Id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); 

    if(key == 0)
        db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
    else
        db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

3 - You can ask mapping metadata to get  the key:

```
public static void Look(LEBAEntities db, object obj) {
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var type = typeof (IdentityUser);
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    IEnumerable<string> retval = (IEnumerable<string>)objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
        .GetType(type.Name, type.Namespace, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace)
        .MetadataProperties.First(mp => mp.Name == "Id")
        .Value;
.
.
.
```